# Problema cogiendo datos de api

Tags: api, digitalocean

Estoy intentando sacar datos de la API de digital ocean, con este comando me devuelve un diccionario de datos :

```
    curl -X GET \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN" \
  "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account"
```

estos son los datos que me devuelve :

```
{
"account": {
"droplet_limit": 25,
"floating_ip_limit": 5,
"email": "sammy@digitalocean.com",
"uuid": "b6fr89dbf6d9156cace5f3c78dc9851d957381ef",
"email_verified": true,
"status": "active",
"status_message": " "
}
}
```

pero porque por ejemplo si quiero llamar a un dato específico del diccionario, por ejemplo, uuid:

```
  curl -X GET \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN" \
  "https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account/uuid"
```

No me devuelve solo ese dato y me sale : `{"id":"not_found","message":"The resource you were accessing could not be found."}`

Answer (score 0):

DigitalOcean usa la arquitectura [REST](https://restfulapi.net/rest-architectural-constraints/). Solo puedes acceder a los recursos usando las rutas en la url. En tu caso si accedes a /v2/account te devuelve el recurso que este asociado a esa ruta pero la ruta /v2/account/uuid no existe por lo tanto te devuelve ese error.

El diccionario que te devuelve es la representacion JSON del recurso. Si necesitas el valor de algun campo dentro del json. Lo has de cargar en tu programa para poder acceder a el.

Si tienes python puedes hacer esto para imprimir el valor de uuid

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN" \
"https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account" | python -c "import sys,json; print(json.load(sys.stdin)['account']['uuid'])"
```

Tambien puedes usar [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) que sirve para procesar json desde la terminal.

```
curl -X GET \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN" \
"https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/account" | jq .account.uuid
```

Comment: y si quiero coger los datos del solo ese dato(uuid) para meterlo en una variable?

Comment: Si quiero coger solo el dato json de uuid, para mostrarlo en una variable por ejemplo

Comment: He puesto un ejemplo de como hacerlo usando python. Puedes usar cualquier entorno que te permita procesar json para sacar el valor de uuid.